# What is the mechanism of diminished intelligence?

Tags: 28-days-later

In 28 Days Later, it is not immediately clear that the affected from the "Rage" virus are actually unintelligent -- it seems like they are simply preoccupied by extreme anger towards unaffected humans.

However, the soldiers have one of the affected chained up and the leader discusses that they just need to wait things out because Rage victims are not going to ever plant crops or do anything in furtherance of their own survival and therefore will starve within weeks; indeed the chained-up person looks and acts very zombie like.

Is it explained that one of the effects of the virus is to cause brain damage in addition to the extreme anger? Is it possible that a side effect of nonstop anger is to damage the brain -- the virus does not directly kill neurons but, for example, the hormones that are released actually cause cell death (which in real life I think can happen)?

Note: In rabies, which maybe is related to the Rage virus, there is certainly cell death and if Rage worked the same way, the affected would die pretty soon after they showed symptoms. The vicious behavior of animals (I do not think it has this effect in humans) that have rabies is a side effect not the primary effect of rabies which is simply killing neurons -- the animal's brain is damaged, it may be physically uncomfortable and confused so it attacks. However, Rage works so fast that the effects we see must be the primary effect -- the virus somehow makes humans (and chimps) vicious before any neuron death because 30 seconds or whatever is far too fast for that.

Note: One of the comments mentions the infected soldier, Mailer, beckoning and this can be pretty clearly seen at the end of this clip: [Meet Mailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDYfkuvFbdw&t=105s)

This may indicate that there is in fact some intelligence left although it seems to be "in service" of spreading the infection and barely there or he would have acted rationally -- I have seen movies where the infected actually can speak but still want to kill/spread virus.

Comment: I always interpreted it as the infected being so mad that they kind of reverted to the most basic instincts of human-beings, whilst still being alive and displaying some level of intelligence. For example, when the Major left and Jim was left alone with Mailer (the chained guy), the latter seemingly called Jim to come closer with subtle hand sign, until he was close enough to attempt an attack.

Comment: @Clockwork: are you saying the chained up guy tried to lure someone? Interesting. Also, there is some evidence that the affected can speak -- some background voice saying, "I hate you!" or something -- I am remembering this from long ago.

Comment: Yeah, the "I hate you!" scene was when they stopped for gas near a gas truck, and Jim entered the restaurant because he wanted cheese burger, after they already stopped at the grocery store to fill up. When he said "hello?", an infected boy attempted to jump him, so he defended himself, and before killing the boy, you could hear that sentence in a child voice. But apparently, the director (or someone from the movie making team), admitted that was an omission: they were supposed to add an ominous effect to make it sound like a distance echo or something, instead of a clear voice.

Comment: @Clockwork: Many chances for infected to speak, never heard it anywhere else. Do u have a clip with the "beckoning" gesture? I would like to see that -- certainly qualifies as an interesting detail. Do see it discussed anyplace? As for the kid -- he was meant to say it or he improvised? Very interesting improvisation for a kid.

Comment: For the infected boy talking, there is a trivia here but no source: https://28dayslater.fandom.com/wiki/Infected_Child _"Just before Jim kills the Infected Child, the child hissed "I hate you!" at him, despite the Child's mouth not moving to match the words. Danny Boyle confirmed that the child speaking in this scene was due to an audio error, and in the 28 Days Later comics, it was implied by Gordon and Luis Rodriguez that Infected cannot talk."_

Comment: And [here's a link with Mailer](https://youtu.be/mDYfkuvFbdw?t=91) (warning: potentially **NSFW** because zombie lookalike, blood, etc.). Notice the very subtle movement of the fingers at 1:33 and 1:34, like asking Jim to come closer. Beside that, he was also acting calm enough that you might feel pity for him, instead of endlessly trying to attack. Edit: Looks like you found the same link.

Comment: Also good to know: the infected ones seem to be capable of sneaking on you silently when they know you are not aware of their presence yet, such as the boy trying to jump Jim from the back, the infected attacking the Major when he went searching for Jim, the infected that attacked Jim in his kitchen. However, the infected soldier wearing an ushanka hat was acting funny when he saw his own reflection in the mirror (I'm glad I got to watch a movie with a pseudo-zombie seeing himself in a mirror though).